# How to use a TypeScript const both with typeof and as a value in a module?

Tags: typescript

I am struggling with trying to use a string constant both as a type for a discriminated union tag type and a runtime value.

`index.ts`

```
import * as helper from './helper';

function test() {
    const blue = helper.makeBlueColor();
    const red = helper.makeRedColor();
}

test();
```

`helper.ts`

```
import './types';

export function makeBlueColor(): BlueColor {
    return { type: BLUE_COLOR_TYPE };
}

export function makeRedColor(): RedColor {
    return { type: RED_COLOR_TYPE };
}
```

`types.ts`

```
const BLUE_COLOR_TYPE = 'blue';
const RED_COLOR_TYPE = 'red';

type BlueColor = { type: typeof BLUE_COLOR_TYPE; }

type RedColor = { type: typeof RED_COLOR_TYPE; }
```

I a running this using `ts-node index.ts` and am using the same TSC version in VS Code and in Node. In VS Code in `helper.ts` I can Ctrl+click through `BLUE_COLOR_TYPE` to `types.ts`. When I run the code, though, I get:

```
return { type: BLUE_COLOR_TYPE };
        ^
```

*ReferenceError: BLUE_COLOR_TYPE is not defined*

I see why that would be the case, `types.ts` is not a module, so it acts as an ambient type declaration, but is not exported in the compiled output. But turning `types.ts` into a module would mean I would have to import types by name for use in all files! Surely there must be a better way. I thought maybe `constants.ts` with `export`ed `const`s would be a way to go, but for me to be able to `import` those in `types.ts` I'd have to turn it into a module. So it's sort of circular.

Using my files as presented, what is the next step to make it so that I can use the `const`s in `types.ts` both as types with `typeof` and as values?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally specify the types you want to use in your import statement.

```
import { RED_COLOR_TYPE, BLUE_COLOR_TYPE } from './types';
```

You would make the members of the types module available by exporting them:

```
export const BLUE_COLOR_TYPE = 'blue';
```

You can compile this style of import to the flavour of your choice using the `--module` compiler option.

Alternatively, if you are actually loading all of the scripts yourself, make sure they are all present, correct, and loaded in the right order.